# http.post not working in ios ionic 2

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am working on ionic 2. This code works fine in android device, but in iOS device api call is not working and can't see any error in Xcode console I have tried NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads but it's not working.

```
sendMsg(data)
  {
    this.headers = new Headers();
    this.headers.append('Content-Type','application/json');  
    let body=data;
    return this.http.post
       ('https://www.example.com/api/',JSON.stringify(body),
         {headers:this.headers})
    .map(res => res.json());
  }
```

Comment: Try to inspect the XHR activity with the iOS Simulator and Safari Developer Console.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.